# Given the length of chords, find possible values of two parts of a chord

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me solve this problem? What are x and y in the problem?

Chords AB and CD intersect in the circle at E. If AE = 6, BE = 4, CD = 11, then the equation needed to determine the possible values of CE and DE is

A) x + y = 11, 
B) xy = 24, 
C) x^2 - 11x -24 = 0, 
D) x^2 - 11x + 24 = 0, 
E) None of these

[image]

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not given in the question?

Comment: No, the problem does not say what are x and y, and the correct answer is D. I don't get it.

Comment: It seems like A is the only reasonable choice. Because $CE+ED=CD=11$, so I suppose it asks about what formula can help you determine the value of $CE$ and $ED$. $x,y$ refer to the values of the lengths of CE and ED

Comment: Get to know the [Power of a Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) theorems. In particular here, the "chord-chord power theorem".

Comment: Dubububu, answer key says the correct answer is D.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is D). According to the power-chord theorem,
$$CE\times DE=AE\times BE$$
or $$CE\times DE=24$$
Given that $CD=11$, the desired system of equations follows:
$$x+y=11$$
$$xy=24$$
where $x,y=CE,DE$.
This gives the quadratic
$$a^2-11a+24$$
of which $x$ and $y$ are its roots.

Comment: Edward, Thank you for help. This is a bad, at least confused, test problem. Looks like that A, B, and D all are right answers.

Comment: @teamember: The problem could perhaps be better. However, A and B are *not* "right answers", since neither equation *individually* tells you the lengths of the segments. You need *both* equations to get those lengths, and it turns out that D combines the knowledge of A and B.